# What are some good guides to touch screen programming?

Tags: touchscreen

This would ideally be done in C# and is intended for larger form factors (NOT mobiles.).

I'm a novice in this area, but would users suggest Silverlight 
(Can it process touch screens?) or WPF or are other technologies better?

Ideally this would involve users tracing shapes with their fingers or a stylus, and the system automatically marking it.

My background is .net/c# web development.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicates/related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481459/guidelines-for-touchscreens-systems, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144730/things-to-consider-when-writing-for-touch-screen, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607675/smallest-button-size-on-a-touchscreen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc872774.aspx) on Touch Guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the windows controls are big enough for a finger tip and is readable. Also, ensure that there is a easy way to pop up a right-click context menu, on the pocket pc for example, if you hold down the stylus on the touch screen, a dancing circles appear in formation, then a popup menu appears, the same could be said for accessing menu options using big fonts (96dpi is the normal standard font size).

Other than that, don't do anything fanciful to the screen layout, i.e. custom colors etc, as you could end up confusing people with non-standard ways of interacting. Keep it plain and simple, grey buttons etc, this is more of common sense that needs to be applied here and is the same across the board.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.